# webscraping extension in chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, web

I am trying to extract multiple paragraphs from a news site using the web scraping extension but it only captures the first paragraph.

Comment: Please provide the code you are having trouble with, or alternatively the extension name so that troubleshooting can be done. Without this info there is no way to answer the question, thanks!

Comment: sorry for replying very late... this is the extension name - Web Scraper - Free Web Scraping
Offered by: webscraper.io

Comment: We're not support for extensions. You've tagged the question with Python, so if there's Python code you've written, then show it

Answer (score 0):

**Basic Web scraping** works on single page not sure which extension you are using and how the website which is crawled is been coded and extension as well.

Prefer Python - beautifulsoup Library [Link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), If Java - Jsoup [link](https://jsoup.org/) library

Basic Python Tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_VZ7NpVw1Y

There are cases where you need to handle it via **Javascript**
And **more important** Chrome has **localStorage variable of 5mb** you can use it for session, storing data appending table rows etc.

Comment: i use Web Scraper - Free Web Scraping
Offered by: webscraper.io